# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a:not(.someClass... in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a Javascript error in IE10: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a:not(.someClass in this line (it's not the whole thing, '...' denotes rest of function). There's no error in Chrome or Firefox. Is there another way to denote a 'not' which works across all the browsers?
I am using jQuery 1.10.2

```
$("a:not(.someClass").on({
          click: function (e) {...
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question?

Comment: The problem doesn't change by asking the same question again.

Comment: You better have a good reason to downvote the question

Comment: Posting duplicate questions is a good reason IMO. Of course I cannot speak for those who downvoted, but that would be my reason if I had downvoted.

Comment: I suspect one reason might be that you already asked the question and got an answer.

Comment: @Pointy: Where'd that other question go? I thought you posted an answer on it. Or was it someone else that answered?

Comment: @cookiemonster: OP deleted it. Here it is (10k+ users): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947467/javascript-syntax-error-in-ie-when-using-anot-someclass-on

Comment: I have a hard time keeping track of whether I'm hallucinating as it is.

Comment: @FelixKling: I didn't think that was possible after there were answers. But yeah, this is the same issue. Not sure if it's the same user, but it would be quite the coincidence.

Comment: @cookiemonster: It's possible if there are no *upvoted* answers (and yes, it's the same user).

Comment: FYI (although I would assume you'd know about it given your rep), you can [edit] your question if you want to add more information, or change the wording. There is no need to ask a new one.

Comment: @FelixKling: So this user asked a question, got an answer, deleted the question, posted it again, and is now insisting that other users better have a good reason to justify their behavior. Nice.

Comment: Yes I deleted it because it was downvoted and 4 votes to close in a matter of few minutes even though it was a pure js question. I mean WTF!! If you don't like something in the question, SAY SO instead of being click down happy.

Comment: @Felix Because it had 4 close votes for no apparent reason. I didn't want to deal with the crap (IMO) which I saw so I got rid of it.

Comment: @cookie The same behavior from the downvoters/closers was in the other question and I would have asked the same thing over there.  What the chance it's the same question, same day and same user!? Come on!

Comment: Long day @Tony_Henrich?

Comment: Whatever is happening, it doesn't seem correct to close this question based on the claim that it is "off topic".

Comment: To be fair, one if the close reasons is *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."*. Would you deny that this is a typographical error? This question isn't very helpful for others because they will probably not make the same typographical error as you did. The community's opinion probably doesn't change if you repost the question. You got your answer already, so you could have just let it be (my personal opinion). Some questions are just better asked in chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the selector syntax error.

```
$('a:not(.someClass)')
```

You need to close the parens for the `:not()` subexpression.

Comment: No need to refer to something that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich as you wish.